# Using R dygraphs for fractional timepoints?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, rstudio, dygraphs

Is there a hack that exists in order to use the `dygraphs` package in `R Shiny` with fractional timepoints? I understand this pacakge is mainly for time-series data, but I think it would be extremely useful as a survival plot as well.

For example, say I have the following data:

```
samp.data <- data.frame(Months=seq(0,10,by=0.5), Surv=seq(1,0,length.out=21))

head(samp.data)

  Months Surv
1    0.0 1.00
2    0.5 0.95
3    1.0 0.90
4    1.5 0.85
5    2.0 0.80
6    2.5 0.75
```

I know I can do the following:

```
samp.xts <- xts(samp.data[,-1], order.by=as.Date(samp.data[,1]))
dygraph(samp.xts)
```

But this gets rid of some information and the x-axis is a date instead of a value. I have been research the 'dygraphs' javascript library and there seems to be some functionality for non-time-series data as well, but I haven't found anything associated with the `R` package yet. Is there any `javascript` code I can call from the function?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so after playing with it for a while, I think I have it figured out. You have to pass `javascript` functions to the `valueFormatter` and the `axisLabelFormatter`.

```
samp.data <- data.frame(Months=seq(0,10,by=0.5), Surv=seq(1,0,length.out=21))
samp.xts <- xts(samp.data[,-1], order.by=as.POSIXct(10*samp.data[,1],origin=as.Date("1970-01-01")))
```

And here is the graph:

```
dygraph( samp.xts ) %>%
  dyAxis(name="x",
         valueFormatter="function(d){ var date = new Date(d); return (date.getSeconds()/10) }",
         axisLabelFormatter="function(d){ return (d.getSeconds()/10) }"
  )
```

It is definitely a hack, but it gives me what I wanted to see. Note that `valueFormatter` returns a value, where `axisLabelFormatter` returns a date.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that by "fractional timepoints" you mean intra-day data. `dygraphs` can be used with data indexed on `POSIXct`, which will allow you to place points within a day.

In your example you are converting the index to `Date`, which will strip off any times in the data.

Have you tried the following?

```
samp.xts <- xts(samp.data[,-1], order.by=as.POSIXct(samp.data[,1]))
dygraph(samp.xts)
```

*Note the `as.POSIXct`.*

Comment: This is a good start! Is there a way to modify the x-axis so it doesn't show up as dates?

Comment: `dygraphs` is only designed for `xts` objects, which are always indexed on time.

Comment: There should be a way to use `javascript` to modify the x-axis, but I am still in the process of learning `javascript`. I am researching further....

Comment: OK. Just be aware that `dygraphs` is only meant to display timeseries, so it may not be the best tool for the job.